# How do I include ActionBarSherlock in the library so that it is reflected in all the systems?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I've included ActionBarSherlock in my project as a library, though it is not path independent. Thus, when I push it into my repo, the library path gets muddled up. How do I change that? How do I make it path independent?

If it were a Jar file, I could have included it in the lib folder of my project, but it is a library in itself. What to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your project.properties file to see where it is pointing to in regard to ABS..
if it says something like:

`android.library.reference.1=/myfiles/location/bleh/blah/foo/ActionBarSherlock`

and your project that references it is also in /myfiles/location/bleh/blah/foo/ (its nice to keep them in the same folder for simplicity)

you can change it to :

```
android.library.reference.1=../ActionBarSherlock
```

That way when you check out your repo all of your library references will be intact (provided that folder structure is intact on the actual repository).

and yes, despite the project.properties file saying "do not change me ohh nooo!" you can change it without any problems